# How can I remove salt from a saline infused pork sirloin roast?

Tags: salt, pork

How can I remove salt from a saline infused pork roast. I purchased 4 of them.

After making the first one I could not eat it.  I am on a low sodium diet.

Answer (score 2):

Before cooking, Remove any packaging and soak in cold water for 4 - 6 hours changing the water once or twice

Answer (score -3):

One of the best ways to remove salt from food is to cook it with potatos, they will absorb some of the salt out of the meat for you. however, in your particular situation, you may come to find your meat will stay at a higher level of sodium then you would like.

[how to unsalt food](http://www.ehow.com/how_8157729_unsalt-food.html)

Comment: Using potato to lower sodium is a myth that have been debunked. Plus eHow is not a very reliable source.

Comment: @Himarm eHow is paid content, and time and time again the content is either totally wrong, or of very poor quality. Please be nice here!

Comment: I have 5 pages of google saying potatoes work, 0 saying its a myth so show me its a myth...

Comment: http://www.thekitchn.com/can-a-potato-really-fix-a-toosalty-soup-putting-tips-to-the-test-in-the-kitchn-214650

Comment: http://www.genuineideas.com/ArticlesIndex/potatosponge.html

Comment: http://blog.kitchenmage.com/2011/12/debunk-of-day-potato-fixes-over-salted-soup.html

Comment: Let's just assume a second it would work for soup; for the meat it would mean that the salt first needs to go into the water and then from there into the potato. If the salt is already in the water instead of the meat, the potato would serve no purpose anymore, as the salt is no longer in the meat anyway.